# Remove Default Dashlets

Tags: dashlet

Generally, I tend not to use the CiviCRM Home page since it's not a global dashboard. However, recently, I thought some of the dashlets could be beneficial for my users.

My question is: is it possible to remove or hide some of the default dashlets (specifically, CiviCRM Resources, CiviCRM news)?

The last time I visited this feature, I recall that there is no way to reset everyone's dashboard to have the same dashlets correct? DefaultDashlets only sets dashboards for new users but not existing users.

Answer (score 3):

You could update mysql directly:

`UPDATE civicrm_dashboard_contact SET is_active = 0 WHERE dashboard_id IN (1,2);`

1 and 2 are the ones you mentioned. You can double-check with `select id,label from civicrm_dashboard;`

```
+----+------------------------+
| id | label                  |
+----+------------------------+
|  1 | CiviCRM News           |
|  2 | CiviCRM Resources      |
|  3 | Activities             |
|  4 | My Cases               |
|  5 | All Cases              |
|  6 | Case Dashboard Dashlet |
+----+------------------------+
```