# How to configure dashboard for new users

Tags: dashboard, user-dashboard

We have a number of new contacts (about 40) who will be having a signon to Civi and for whom we want their dashboard to show a certain report- and not the 2 default items that a new user currently sees. Display Preferences has some general categories for users, but what we need is a specific dashboard setup for a new user. Is there a way of configuring this for new users?  I guess we could add the new users, login as them and then set this up manually but configuring would be much better, if that's possible.  Civi is at 5.53 and it's Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

[Default Dashlets extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/default-dashlets) does this, though I can't vouch for it at all and it doesn't look much used or recently updated.

You can also update this [directly in the database](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/39743/remove-default-dashlets).

It would be great if there was a simpler way to add default dashlets for new users or to copy dashlets from one user to another.

Comment: Thanks for this - that extension is 'old' & doesn't work.  I'll probably update the database as you suggest.

Comment: You can also access these through API v4, which might be a little more cautious.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Searchkit + formbuilder to create dashlets or dashboard?

There is also a new feature added in form builder i.e [layout](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/22975) worth trying as well

Comment: Yes, I've used SK and the screen created there is what we want to display for these particular users, and not the default ones. But I can't see a way that new users would be set up to get this screen & not the default ones.